# ¿Como puedo desplegar un archivo war en jboss con jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jboss-as-7

Estoy tratando de automatizar el despliegue a un servidor Jboss AS 7.4 con el plugin de maven jboss-as, mi situación es que a mi me entregan el archivo war de la aplicación en un directorio especifico y necesito que jenkins tome ese war y lo despliegue en el servidor jboss, el plugin no es definitivo en realidad cualquier solución es buena siempre y cuando se pueda llevar a cabo con jenkins, hasta ahora esto es lo que tengo:

Tengo mi archivo pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ss</groupId>
<artifactId>ss</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>ss</name>
<description>uses the pom to deploy to Jboss AS 7 with jenkins</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <hostName>localhost</hostName>
    <jbossUser>user</jbossUser>
    <jbossPass>admin</jbossPass>
    <warName>ss</warName>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <force>true</force>
                <hostname>${hostName}</hostname>
                <username>${jbossUser}</username>
                <password>${jbossPass}</password>
                <port>10000</port>
                <fileNames>
                    <fileName>/${warName}.war</fileName>
                </fileNames>
                <name>ss</name>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

al ejecutarlo hace un despliegue al servidor jboss pero del war que genera el pom no del archivo que necesito.

¡muchas gracias por la ayuda!